# How to tell if user pressed back or done?

Tags: ios

I have a 'Create new event' page where the user can click 'Back' on the UINavigationController or 'Done' to create a new event. Both leads to the same page afterwards.

If my user presses "Done" the current object kept at the controller is saved via saveChanges. However, if the user has decided to abandon this even he/she is editing, I need to clean up static files generated by this user during this lifetime of this event.

My only problem is that there is no way for me to differentiate a user from pressing 'Done' or 'Cancel'.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // If user has left this page by either pressing 'Done' or 'Cancel'
    if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject:self]) {
        // If this event is NOT saved aka 'Cancel' is pressed.
        if (![event isUpdated]) {
            // It is important that we only delete videos associated when isNew.
            if (isNew) { 
                NSURL *url = [self getMovieUrl:event.uuid];
                [self deleteMovieByUrlIfExists:url];
            }
            self.event = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (isNew) { 
        event.eventType = eventTypeInput.text;
        event.targetId= [NSNumber numberWithInt:[targetIdInput.text intValue]];
        event.game = game;

        BOOL success = [[DataStore singletonInstance] saveChanges];
        if(success) {
            NSLog(@"Success: Event %@ saved. hasVideo:%d", event.uuid, [event.hasVideo intValue]);
            // TODO [newEvent upload];
            // Also upload the video if possible. 
        } 
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The above code does not work. When the user presses 'Done', deleteMovieByUrlIfExists:url is still called. Anyone knows why?

======
This is how isNew is set.

```
- (void)initWithEvent:(id)sender event:(Event *)ev { 
    isNew = !ev;
    if (isNew) { 
        event = [[DataStore singletonInstance] createEvent];        
    } else { 
        event = ev;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you associated separate callback functions for done and back button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `[event isUpdated]` and `isNew` always have the same value no matter what action the user takes. Set a flag (a `BOOL` ivar, for example) in `done:` and check the value of the flag in `viewWillDisappear:`.

Comment: actually isNew is set by the init function and not event isUpdated.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a delegate for your view controller , delegates are used to transfer data based on actions to other view controllers , i strongly advice you to read more on delegates but here's a simple instructions to do it

```
@protocol viewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
//define the delegate methods
-(void)backButtonPressed;
-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender

@end

@interface ViewContorller : xxx
{
id <viewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
```

now in the action method and after you finish processing data you write this line of code

```
 - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
 [delegate backButtonPressed:sender]
 }
```

now all the view controllers implementing this delegate will get notified of this , you should create two delegate methods one for the back button and another for the done button

```
//in the parent view controller .h file add the delegate to the definition
 @interface MyViewController: UIViewController <viewControllerDelegate>

//in the .m file implement the delegate methods
-(void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
  //this method will get called when the back button is pressed
}
 -(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
  //this method will get called when the done button is pressed
 }
```

Comment: How would pressing Back on the UINavigationController trigger backButtonPressed?

Comment: putting this line of code inside the back button target **[delegate backButtonPressed:sender]** will tell all the classes implementing the <viewControllerDelegate> that the button had been pressed

Comment: no that's not what I mean. I mean what is triggering backButtonPressed? You can't Ctrl-drag the UINavigationController's back button to this method FYI.

Comment: of course not , you should add your target by code , here's how you do it : UIButton b = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame];   [ b addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControllEventTouchUpInside ];     UIBarButtonItem b1 = [UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:b];  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem= b1;

Comment: in summary to my code above , define your button by code , customize it's size and image and title , add it's target , define a UIBarButton from the UIButton and finally set your navigation bar left button to the UIBarButton